# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{c_1^n+c_2^n+\ldots+c_m^n} = \max\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals

Let $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{c_1^n+c_2^n+\ldots+c_m^n} = \max\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\}$$

My attempt: Since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{c_1^n+c_2^n+\ldots+c_m^n} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\max\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{\max\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \max\{\sqrt[n]{c_1^n},\sqrt[n]{c_2^n},\ldots,\sqrt[n]{c_m^n}\}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\max\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\}=\max\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\}$$

it follows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{c_1^n+c_2^n+\ldots+c_m^n}$ is bounded, but I don't think it's monotonically decreasing, at least I can't prove this. Can anybody tell me whether the approach I have chosen is a good one, whether what I have done is correct and how to finish the proof?

Comment: Not sure why you'd think that first inequality is true. Maybe missing something?

Comment: One thing to note is: You don't have a $\lim{\sqrt[n]{c_1^n\cdots}}$ until you prove that the limit exists. So any statement that you wrote with the limit before actually proving it's existence is not true.

Comment: Your upper bound proof looks correct assuming that your second and third steps were supposed to be: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{n\max\{c_1^n,c_2^n,\ldots,c_m^n\}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{\max\{c_1^n,c_2^n,\ldots,c_m^n\}}$

Comment: @boywholived $m$ is finite, so that should be fine?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt. Oh yes, I just meant to convey an point and was lazy to type. Sorry if that caused a confusion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short proof.

Let $c=\max\{c_1,c_2,\dots,c_m\}$ and note that:

$$c^n \leq c_1^n+c_2^n+\dots+c_m^n \leq mc^n$$

Now take the $n$th root, and see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{m} = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Being $\{c_1,\cdots,c_m \}$ a fine set of number, exist and index $i\in [1,m]$ such that 
$$
\max\{c_1,\cdots,c_m \}=c_i.
$$
Then results
$$
\sqrt{c_1^n+\cdots+c_m^n} = \sqrt{c_i ^ n \Big(\frac{c_1^n}{c_i^n}+\frac{c_2^n}{c_i^n}+\frac{c_3^n}{c_i^n}+\cdots+1+\cdots+\frac{c_m^n}{c_i^n}\Big)}
$$
where the number $1$ correpond to the $i$-th element. Being $c_i$ the max, then every ratio $c_1/c_i ,c_2/c_i,\cdots,c_m/c_i \leq 1$, i.e
$$
\frac{c_j}{c_i}< 1,\,\forall j=1,\cdots,m,\, j\neq i
$$ 
then for $n\to \infty$ follows
$$
\Big(\frac{c_j}{c_i}\Big)^n\to 0,\, \forall j\neq i
$$
So being $c_1>0$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[1/n]{c_1^n+\cdots+c_m^n}}&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{c_i ^ n \Big(\frac{c_1^n}{c_i^n}+\frac{c_2^n}{c_i^n}+\frac{c_3^n}{c_i^n}+\cdots+1+\cdots+\frac{c_m^n}{c_i^n}\Big)}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}{c_i\sqrt{\frac{c_1^n}{c_i^n}+\frac{c_2^n}{c_i^n}+\frac{c_3^n}{c_i^n}+\cdots+1+\cdots+\frac{c_m^n}{c_i^n}}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}{c_i\sqrt{\Big(\frac{c_1}{c_i}\Big)^n+\cdots+1+\cdots+\Big(\frac{c_m}{c_i}\Big)^n}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}{c_i \cdot \sqrt{1}}\\
&=&c_i=\max\{c_1,\cdots,c_m\}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

You can see there is an error in your approach if you consider a simple example.  Let $c_1=2$ and $c_2=\cdots=c_m=0$.  Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{c_1^n+c_2^n+\cdots+c_m^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n}=2$$
but

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\max\{c_1,c_2\ldots,c_m\}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2}=1$$

so your first inequality does not always hold.