# Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}}=\max(a,b)$ if $(a_n,b_n)\to(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, radicals

I know well that:

$$ \max(x,y)=\frac{x+y+\lvert y-x\rvert}{2}$$

but I do not see how that it would be useful.

Comment: $max(a, b)$ not max  ($a_n,b_n$)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111089

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=\max \{a,b\}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111089/how-to-show-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtnanbn-max-a-b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $a \geq b$. Then

$$ a \leq  \sqrt[n]{a^n + b^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{a^n + a^n} = 2^{1/n} a$$

Now apply the sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For positive $a$ and $b$, note that
$$(a^n+b^n)^{1/n} = a\left(1+\left(\tfrac ba\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$$
and
$$(a^n+b^n)^{1/n} = b\left(1+\left(\tfrac ab\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$$