# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n}$

I'm stuck. Tried to apply the squeeze theorem, but found only the $\le$ side, which is $\sqrt[n]{5^n}$, approaching 5.

How do I proceed from there?

Comment: $5^n\le 3^n+5^n\le2\cdot 5^n$.

Comment: Here are a few more general questions:
[How to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=\max \{a,b\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111089) (and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1111089)) or  [Convergence of $\sqrt[n]{x^n+y^n}$ (for $x, y > 0$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80340) (and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/80340).)

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$$\sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n}=5\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the comment of David Mitra. 
$5^n\le 3^n+5^n\le 2*5^n$.

If you take limits, you get $5\le \lim\sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n}\le \lim\sqrt[n]{2}*5$. 
Since $\lim\sqrt[n]{2}=1$, you get that your limit is $5$.

Please upvote David Mitra's comment, not my answer.

Comment: +1 for the attitude. I was writing a comment to all David to post his comment as an answer when you already posted it. But so glad about the acknowledgement

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(3^n+5^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(3^n+5^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(3^n+5^n\right)}{n}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(3^n+5^n\right)}{n}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(5^n\right)+\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n\right)}{n}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(5^n\right)}{n}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\ln\left(5\right)}{n}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(5\right)}{1}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(5\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\ln\left(5\right)\right)=e^{\ln\left(5\right)}=5$$

Comment: Thank you! I wondered if there was a exp ln solution :)