# Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{3^{n} +5^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, radicals

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{3^{n} +5^{n}}$$

Attempt:

The only sort of manipulation that has come to mind is: $$e^{\frac{1}{n}ln(e^{n\ln(3)} + e^{n\ln(5)})}$$

So what is the trick to successfully evaluate this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms

Comment: By [searching in  Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Crightarrow%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7B3%5E%7Bn%7D%20%2B5%5E%7Bn%7D%7D%24&p=1) you can find a few copies of this question and some very similar question. For example: [Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1521019) or [Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2215066)

Comment: And probably looking at various generalizations of this might be useful, too. Such as: [How to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=\max \{a,b\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111089) (and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1111089)) or  [Convergence of $\sqrt[n]{x^n+y^n}$ (for $x, y > 0$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80340) (and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/80340).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**hint:** There is a standard trick....: $5^n < 3^n+5^n < 2\cdot 5^n$, and in general if $0 < a < b$, then $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} = b$

Comment: more general https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms

Answer (score 3):

Squeeze

$$5\leq \sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n}\leq 5\sqrt[n]{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

With the well known limit of the exponential  $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow\infty} \frac 1 {e^{n}}=0 $

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{3^{n} +5^{n}}=5\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{  \left(\frac 35\right)^{n} +1}=5\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{  \frac 1 {e^{n(\ln 5 -\ln 3)}} +1}=5(0+1)^0=5$$

Answer (score 2):

By Bernoulli's inequality,
if $x > 0$
and $n \ge 1$,
$(1+x)^n 
\ge 1+nx$.

Therefore
$(1+x/n)^n 
\ge 1+x$
so that
$(1+x)^{1/n}
\le 1+x/n
$.

Therefore,
if $0 < a < b$
then
$\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}
=b\sqrt[n]{1+(a/b)^n}
\le b(1+\frac{(a/b)^n}{n})
= b+\frac{b(a/b)^n}{n}
\lt b+\frac{b}{n}
$
since
$a/b < 1$
and
$\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}
=b\sqrt[n]{1+(a/b)^n}
\gt b
$.

Thererfore
$b 
\lt \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}
\lt b + \frac{b}{n}
$
so that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}
= b
$.

Comment: Very nice +1 for the mention of Bernouilli's famous inequality ...

Comment: I find it impressive how often that elementary inequality is enough.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot\log\left(\left(\dfrac{3}{5}\right)^{n}+1\right)\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left(\left(\dfrac{3}{5}\right)^{n}+1\right)^{1/n}\rightarrow e^{0}=1,
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{3^{n}+5^{n}}=5\left(\left(\dfrac{3}{5}\right)^{n}+1\right)^{1/n}\rightarrow 5.
\end{align*}

Comment: I've never seen this techinque used before. Could you explain it a bit more? I'm interested in the different approach.

Comment: Take $\log$ first, and compute what's the limit, after that, take $e$ to recover back to the original one.

Comment: Isn't that what you already had in mind as you have written there?

Comment: I did @user284331, but I am trying to see where that fraction form came from

Comment: $(3^{n}+5^{n})^{1/n}=(5^{n}((3/5)^{n}+1))^{1/n}=5((3/5)^{n}+1)^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The correct maniplulation by exponential is

$$\sqrt[n]{3^{n} +5^{n}}=(3^{n} +5^{n})^\frac1n=e^{\frac{\log (3^n+5^n)}{n}}\to5$$

indeed

$$\frac{\log (3^n+5^n)}{n}=\frac{\log 5^n+\log \left(1+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n\right)}{n}=\frac{n\log 5+\log \left(1+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n\right)}{n}=$$
$$=\log 5+\frac{\log \left(1+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n\right)}{n}\to \log5+0=\log 5$$