# Limit of the sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{4^n + 5^n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have been trying to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{4^n + 5^n}}$$

What methods should I try in order to proceed?

I was advised to use "Limit Chain Rule", but I believe there is a different approach.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80340/convergence-of-sqrtnxnyn-for-x-y-0?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111089/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/326172/321264

Answer (score 8):

Hint:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{4^n + 5^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}5{\sqrt[n]{\frac{4}{5^n}^n + 1}}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Courtesy of the [Sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem),
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}=\max (a,b)\quad$ where $a,b>0$.

Answer (score 0):

By the root test for a power series, this equivalent to the reciprocal of the radius of convergence of the following:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(4^n+5^n)x^n$$

Which is a basic geometric series with radius of convergence $1/5$, so the limit is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4^n+5^n}=1/R=5$$

Comment: It is to be hoped the motivation was not to determine the radius of convergences of said series. ;-) More seriously this feels borderline circular, and in any case not adequate.

Comment: @quid haha, yup.  But I wanted to be different (∩＿∩)